# How to update tile in every seconds using Windows 8 metro style apps

Tags: winrt-async

In my Windows 8 metro style app, I want to update tile in every second. Is it Possible in WinRt apps? Please give me a solution for this issue

Answer (score 2):

The rate at which app tiles are refreshed is determined by the OS and cannot be influenced by the app. Background tasks are limited to running once every 15 minutes and the BadgeUpdater can only be scheduled every 30 minutes.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.periodicupdaterecurrence.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This might be closer to what you are expecting to do.

Here's a solution for every minute (not second):

[Tile Update every minute](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Tile-Update-every-minute-68dbbbff)